# How can i set the footer to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, footer

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Slide-Up Dialogue Box</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}
#container {
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
}
#header {
background: #ff0;
padding: 10px;
}
#body {
padding: 10px;
padding-bottom: 60px;
}
#footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
background: #6cf;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="body"></div>
<div id="footer">
Who is Online?
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I place the footer at the bottom of the page? I've tried experimenting with padding, bottom and margin but I haven't been very successful so far. Can someone tell me how to place the footer at the bottom of the page? Thanks

Comment: Try to add position:fixed to footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this one sir:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}
#container {
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
}
#header {
background: #ff0;
padding: 10px;
}
#body {
padding: 10px;
padding-bottom: 60px;
}
#footer {
position: fixed;;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
background: #6cf;
text-align:center;
}
```

[HERE MY CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/5et41rfc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `body` height to 100%. Currently the body covers only upto the content you have. There was no explicit height set for the body element.

Since body needs to calculate 100% of the parent element, set `html` height to 100% as well.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Slide-Up Dialogue Box</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
    #container {
      min-height: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    #header {
      background: #ff0;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    #body {
      padding: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 60px;
    }
    #footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      background: #6cf;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <div id="footer">
      Who is Online?
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aim to "fix" your element to the bottom of the screen, set:

```css
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

On a side note, it might be a good idea for you to start learning about HTML5 elements like "footer" instead of using divs for everything. Also note that id's are unique and styling is best applied in mass/generically (use classes instead).